# How do I use wp_nav_menu?

Tags: theme-development, css

I try to add dynamically a menu which structure of css ul/li link look like that

```
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#infinite">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#whatwedo">What We Do</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>                    
            </ul>
          </div>        
        </div>
      </nav>
```

I try it to register

```
  <?php
              wp_nav_menu(array(
              "theme_location" => "",
                  'menu_class'=> 'navbar-nav ml-auto'
              'container_class' => 'navbar navbar-expand-md tm-navbar')); ?>
```

but know only how to add class to `<ul>` but not to all `<li>` it make huge problem because my nav menu looks ugly.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464505/how-to-add-class-in-li-using-wp-nav-menu-in-wordpress), seems like the simplest solution, instead of using a Walker to add a single class

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach: use inherited CSS classes.

```
.navbar-nav.ml-auto > li {
   background: yellow;
}

.navbar-nav.ml-auto > li > a {
   color: blue;
}
```

That way, you only need to set the class on the `<ul>`.